# How can I get details of likes on iCloud Shared Albums using PhotoKit

Tags: cocoa-touch, icloud, photokit

I've got a `PHFetchResult` containing the user's iCloud Shared Albums, however I can't find a way to determine whether a photo has been liked by one of the people it is shared with.

I've checked the metadata of the `PHAsset`s that are returned, but the only vaguely related property is `favourite`, but that only records whether the user has hit the heart button in their own Photos app, not the likes from people who the asset has been shared with.

It looks like this data isn't available - the fact that I can't find anything in the docs suggests this - but I want to ask in case StackOverflow knows better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just spent about ten minutes combing the documentation, and running [Google searches like this](https://www.google.com/search?q=favorite+site%3Adeveloper.apple.com), and couldn't find any way to do this. I would expect this to be fairly easy to find if it existed. I'm 99.9% sure that if this existed I would have found it.

I'd really like to be proven wrong!

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you're right, at least for the time being; here's hoping Apple add this capability in the future. I was leaving this open in case anyone knew differently, but it's been long enough now. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1):

*I've been on a similar hunt and even finding this question took me a while! I was surprised not more people have sought out this functionality. There's not much literature on this that I could find.*

Related question [How to Get iCloud Shared Albums Owner Details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59044586/1459103) show the existence of `PHCloudSharedAlbum`, which I can verify with basic debugging.

```
let collections = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .albumCloudShared, options: nil)
print("fetchAssetCollections:")
for i in 0..<collections.count  {
    if collections[i].localizedTitle == "My Test Shared Album" {
        print(collections[i])
    }
}
```

Although this type of asset collection exists, it does not appear in the current iOS SDK/API docs as of Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4.1 / Swift 5. It seems it's private and not intended for public use.

```
<PHCloudSharedAlbum: 0x155e2fe30> ED1EB808-33D8-4E71-BD3F-79FCD616A87C/L0/040, title:"My Test Shared Album", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=1/101
```

Exact Google searches for "PHCloudSharedAlbum" yield a few GitHub repos with (de-compiled?) source code for Photos.framework, but even the fields in there are very limited.

```
short  _cloudAlbumSubtype;
bool  _cloudMultipleContributorsEnabled;
NSNumber * _cloudOwnerEmailKey;
NSString * _cloudOwnerFirstName;
NSString * _cloudOwnerFullName;
NSString * _cloudOwnerLastName;
bool  _owned;
```

Incidental public facing Apple doc, [If Shared Albums aren't working](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201077), implies (by my interpretation) that this social information is not directly tied to assets in iCloud photo collections.

> Any comments or likes attached to a photo or video in a shared album aren't saved with the photo or video.

Or at least, if that information is tied to photos and videos, it's not exposed. It does not seem available to users exporting iCloud shared photo albums or to developers.