# How to Get iCloud Shared Albums Owner Details

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, icloud

I am working on getting iCloud shared album details.

I successfully Getting all iCloud share album using this code.

```
NSMutableArray *cloudFetchResultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *cloudFetchResultLabel = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *cloudFetchResultPersonName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

PHFetchResult *CloudShared = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAlbumCloudShared options:nil];
for(PHCollection *collection in CloudShared)
{

    if ([collection isKindOfClass:[PHAssetCollection class]])
    {
        PHAssetCollection *assetCollection = (PHAssetCollection *)collection;

            PHFetchOptions *options = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
            options.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mediaType in %@", self.picker.mediaTypes];
            options.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO]];

            PHFetchResult *assetsFetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:assetCollection options:options];
            if(assetsFetchResult.count>0)
            {
                [cloudFetchResultArray addObject:assetsFetchResult];
                [cloudFetchResultLabel addObject:collection.localizedTitle];

            }
    }
}
```

But I didn't getting iCloud shared album Owner details.
For Ex. FirstName,Lastname,FullName etc..

For EX: [image: Sample Image]

When I debugging at that time i showing this all info:

[image]

But i didn't finding any solution for getting this value.also i look **Photo Framework** but in this framework i didn't found any **PHCloudSharedAlbum** class.

So Please Help Me for Getting Shared album Information.
Let Me Know any more information required.

Thank You In Advance.